# How can I avoid losing generics on instances when returning from a generic static method? If not, why does Java have this limitation?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Given the following

```
public interface Receiver<T> {
  void onReceive(T t);
}

public static class Doer<T> {
  public void doSomething(Receiver<T> receiver) {
    // Stuff
  }
}

public static class ReceiverHelper {
  public static ReceiverHelper help() {
    return new ReceiverHelper();
  }

  public <T> ReceiverCreator<T> creator() {
    return new ReceiverCreator<>();
  }
}

public static <T> Receiver<T> directReceiver() {
  return new ReceiverCreator<T>().create();
}

public static <T> Receiver<T> directStaticReceiver() {
  return ReceiverCreator.staticCreate();
}

public static <T> ReceiverCreator<T> directReceiverCreator() {
  return new ReceiverCreator<>();
}

public static class ReceiverCreator<E> {

  public static <E> Receiver<E> staticCreate() {
    return new ReceiverCreator<E>().create();
  }

  public static <E> ReceiverCreator<E> staticCreator() {
    return new ReceiverCreator<E>();
  }

  public Receiver<E> create() {
    return t -> { };
  }
}
```

The following test cases are present. I'm particularly wondering why the compile error steps lose their type and go back up to Object. Specifically, `doer.doSomething(directReceiverCreator().create());` is the API I'm trying to design and expose in this project.

```
public void tesReceiver() {
  Doer<Integer> doer = new Doer<>();

  doer.doSomething(directReceiver()); // Fine
  doer.doSomething(new ReceiverCreator().create()); // Result type erased
  doer.doSomething(new ReceiverCreator<>().create()); // Compile error, returns Receiver<Object>
  doer.doSomething(new ReceiverCreator<Integer>().create()); // Fine
  doer.doSomething(ReceiverCreator.staticCreate()); // Fine
  doer.doSomething(ReceiverCreator.staticCreator().create()); // Compile error, returns Receiver<Object>
  doer.doSomething(directStaticReceiver()); // Fine

  // The ideal case
  doer.doSomething(directReceiverCreator().create()); // Compile error, returns Receiver<Object>

  doer.doSomething(ReceiverTest.<Integer>directReceiverCreator().create()); // Fine
  doer.doSomething(ReceiverHelper.help().creator().create()); // Compile error, returns Receiver<Object>
}
```

Comment: You have no inner classes. All you have are static nested classes, which share nothing with their enclosing class. Your code is failing to compile due to insufficient type inference, not the non-propagation of type parameters to unrelated classes.

Comment: Specifically, the type constraint on the argument of `doSomething()` propagates onto the `create()` call, but not onto the target of that call (`new ReceiverCreator()`). This is why the examples where you can capture the type param directly on the `staticCreate()` and `directStaticReceiver()` calls work and others don't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the title to be clearer. This is an example implementation, while the real one I'm working on *is* an inner class :). 

Is this non-propagation a limitation of java or is there a nuance of transitive generics that I'm missing?

Comment: Non-propagation is the only sane and consistent behavior applicable. With true inner classes you can easily add a method to the enclosing class that produces the receiver with the type parameter propagated.

Comment: Something like this?

```java
public static class ParameterizedReceiverHelper<T> {
  
  public static <T> ParameterizedReceiverHelper<T> make() {
    return new ParameterizedReceiverHelper<>();
  }
  
  public ReceiverCreator<T> creator() {
    return new ReceiverCreator<>();
  }
}
```

Comments aren't good for code snippets, but if I'm understanding right (have a parameterized enclosing class that produces a receiver with the type parameter propagated), that gives me the same result. A non-parameterized enclosing class (see `ReceiverHelper` above) doesn't either.

Comment: In general, as soon as you have to write `<T> ReturnType<T> methodName()`, it signals that this `T` is unrelated to the `T` of the declaring class. If you used different letters, it would be more obvious.

Comment: I don't think any of my examples do that on a parameterized enclosing class's method though

Comment: You don’t loose a type in any of the examples. You didn’t specify a type and the compiler has to infer the missing type. Not being able to find out what you haven’t specified is entirely different to *loosing* something. And it hasn’t anything to do with type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

static method is belongs to the class definition, not to a particular instance. So using your example

```
public class ParameterizedReceiverHelper<T> { 
    public static <T>ParameterizedReceiverHelper<T> make() { 
        return new ParameterizedReceiverHelper<>(); 
    } 

    public ReceiverCreator<T> creator() { 
        return new ReceiverCreator<>(); 
    } 
}
```

Whilst Generic Type can only be applied to an instance/object.

```
ParameterizedReceiverHelper<Integer> helperInt = new    ParameterizedReceiverHelper<>();
ParameterizedReceiverHelper<String> helperString = new ParameterizedReceiverHelper<>();    

helperString.make();
helperInt.make();
```

both calls to `make()` above are actually `ParameterizedReceiverHelper.make()` and thus there is no type associated.

More info can be found on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createStatic